# Do the inversions of V7 always support the other 3 tones of the chord?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-inversions, chord-voicings

Since you can only use 4 notes in 4 part writing and the inversions of V7 must be complete then is it correct to say that

- V65 supports ^5 ^2 and ^4
- V43 supports ^7 ^4 and ^5
- V42 supports ^5 ^7 and ^2

is this correct or are certain inversions not used for certain scale degrees?

Comment: In accompaniment parts, V6/5 is often stripped to just scale degrees 5, 7, and 4 (e.g. accompaniment chords of B-F-G in C major).

Answer (score 1):

In standard eighteenth-century voice-leading practice, *inverted seventh chords must be complete*. This changes in more modern practice, but when you're practicing voice leading in this specific style, keep those inverted seventh chords complete.

As such, you're 100% correct. Since the inversion determines the bass note, that determines what three pitches need to be present in the upper voices.

| Inversion | Bass Scale Degree | Upper-Voice Scale Degrees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V65 | 7 | 5, 2, 4 |
| V43 | 2 | 5, 7, 4 |
| V42 | 4 | 5, 7, 2 |

When in root position, however, *then* you can omit the fifth (scale-degree 2) of a V or V7.

Comment: Could either of those tones be equally good candidates for the soprano or are some better than others?

Comment: @armani They all work!

Answer (score 0):

Why must V7 (inverted or not) be complete?  As with all major and minor triads, the 5th is dispensable.

4-part doesn't have to mean 4 voices ALL the time.  In real music we often drop into 3, 2 or even just 1 voice.  The 3rd and 7th are quite sufficient to imply a dom7 harmony.

Comment: Not sure. That is what it says in my textbook.. Harmony and voice leading by Carl Schacter